# huge gap between two divs, divs wont align next to each other.

Tags: html, css

I've looked for this in the search and can't find an answer, either that or I didn't understand it, it's probably a rookie mistake but I'm just not seeing it. Basically I've got two columns of divs side by side and there is a decent gap between the two... in addition to that they won't line up. I had them next to each other before but messed it up. I can't even begin to imagine what the problem is so heres some code (i will be making a style sheet, so don't freak out, and I know it needs a bit more organization. Thanks in advance.

```
     <style type="text/css">
.body_titles {
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:640px;
}
.body_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:640px;
}
#column_left_container {
    float:left;
    width:640px;
}
#content_tab_top_left {
    background-image:url(../img/container_top.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:335px;
    width:640px;
}
#content_tab_center_left {
    background-image:url(../img/container_center.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:311px;
    width:640px;
}
#content_tab_bottom_left {
    background-image:url(../img/container_btm.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:300px;
    width:640px;
}
#padding_div1 {
    padding:2px;
    width:640;
}
#column_right_container {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
}
.body_titlesRIGHT {
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:300px;
}
.body_contentRIGHT {
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:300px;
}
#content_tab_top_right {
    background-image:url(../img/container_top.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:335px;
    width:300px;
}
#content_tab_center_right {
    background-image:url(../img/container_center.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:300px;
}
#content_tab_bottom_right {
    background-image:url(../img/container_btm.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:300px;
}
#padding_div2 {
    padding:2px;
    width:300px;
}
</style>
<div id="body_container"> 
    <div id="columnn_left_container" style="display:inline-block">
        <div id="content_tab_top_left"> 
          <div class="body_titles">
            Title
          </div>
                <div class="body_content">
                    Content
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Tests<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
     <div id="content_tab_center_left">
            <div id="padding_div1"></div>
          <div class="body_titles">
            Title
          </div>
       <div class="body_content">
                    Content
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Tests<br />
                    Test<br />
           Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                </div>
     </div>
    <div id="content_tab_bottom_left">
          <div class="body_titles">
            Title
          </div>
                <div class="body_content">
                    Content
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Tests<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
        <div id="column_right_container" style="display:inline-block">
               <div id="content_tab_top_right">
                  <div class="body_titlesRIGHT">
                    Title
                    </div>
                <div class="body_contentRIGHT">
                    Content
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Tests<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    Test<br />
                    <br />
                </div>
         </div>
             <div id="content_tab_center_right">
                    <div id="padding_div2"></div>
                  <div class="body_titlesRIGHT">
                    Title
                  </div>
                        <div class="body_contentRIGHT">
                            Content
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Tests<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
            <div id="content_tab_bottom_right">
                  <div class="body_titlesRIGHT">
                    Title
                  </div>
                        <div class="body_contentRIGHT">
                            Content
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Tests<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                            Test<br />
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Try changing `#column_right_container` to `float: left;` instead of right.

Comment: I would recommend that you would seriously clean up your code first. For instance you make a call to id body_container which does not even excist. In this case the best thing to do is start over. Trust me eventually it will save you time.

Comment: Ok awesome, got it fixed, how can I mark this question as closed or solved? I'm not seeing an option.
EDIT: actually I am having the spacing issue again, there is a good amount of space between the two columns, I've tried expanding the size of the right column, to what I want it at, but that didnt work at all :/

Comment: oh awesome, maybe this site will make more sense now :P thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your

```
<div id="columnn_left_container" style="display:inline-block">
```

has nn in the **column** part

Change that to

```
<div id="column_left_container" style="display:inline-block">
```

Comment: oh awesome catch, it still didn't solve the problem unfortunately, you can see it visually here, http://sunnahspace.com if that helps, now the middle section of the first column is missing :S

Comment: nevermind, had an extra </div> tag, fixed it all i think. Thanks for your help, guess the lesson of the day is attention to detail :)

Comment: I saw that extra div too!  Was about to mention it as well!

Comment: :) thanks, actually, I am still having the huge space issue. I have them next to eachother again, but the space is now an issue again :/

Comment: It looks like your body_content and body_titles widths are too large.  Make them smaller, about 600px;

Comment: hmm, the background images are set at 640 px with the right column (at should be) 360 px with roughly 24 px between them, for a total of 1024... so I have the content and titles where I want them to be :/ maybe if i set a width for the body container?

Comment: yeah changing content and titles didnt really do anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Well you've got `div#body_container` as a block level element, meaning it stretches to fill 100% of its horizontal space. As a sibling of that, you've got `div#column_right_container` floated right with a `width` of `300px`. `div#column_right_container` will `float` right and **below** `div#body_container` because `div#body_container` isn't floated or inlined.

Comment: no, div body container contains the two columns... but I guess it is unnecessary at this stage, thanks for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite certain what you wish to align.  If you want the `column_right_container` `<div>` to be next to the `body_container`, then all you need to do is add `float: right;` to the `body_container` container.  (re-ordering them will change which one is further right)

Currently the `body_container` is not floating, so it will default to using up the entire width of the page.  Floating it will leave room for another `<div>` next to it.  If you aren't using it already, I would suggest using Firebug.  It allows you to turn off styles one by one to see which ones are affecting your elements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There's no such thing as `float="right"`.  I guess you meant `float:right;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 2 columns (`#column_left_container` and `#column_right_container`) to collapse (side by side), you need to float both columns to left (or change your order and float both to right). You have a `margin-left: 20px;` for the `column_right_container` so you'll always going to have a gap unless you remove it (if that's what you want).

As an alternative, you might want to use positions (`position:relative` for the `#body_container` and `position:absolute` for both columns with `left:n` for `#column_left_container` and `left:n+640px` for the `#column_right_container`.